# EXCEL: TRIM after specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to TRIM a column in excel after specific text. For example, I have the following for example:

> address@domain.com?subject=Enquiry%2C%20sent%20from%20website.com&body=%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A-------------------%0AEnquiry%20from

How do I TRIM all content from the "?" onward? I only want to keep the email address and TRIM everything after and including the email address? I have tried to use the basic TRIM function but because email address lengths vary the TRIM only works from a specific number of characters.

Thank you, Bec

Comment: Use `FIND` and `LEFT`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `LEFT`

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1)-1)
```

Or Replace

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("?",A1),999,"")
```